# Количество отзывов о месте google place

Tags: android, google-places-api

Заключается проблема в получение количества отзывов (google reviews) о месте. Как их можно получить с помощью google place api и возможно ли? В документации возможно только получение массива до 5 отзывов, но не общее количество отзывов о месте.

Если не ясно объяснил, то к примеру у места с названием "M" - 300 отзывов. Как получить число 300?